# Permission denied in file trying to import

Tags: postgresql, windows, permissions

When I try to use `\i` on a file that is not in the psql.exe folder it says `C:: permission denied`. For example I have a file with SQL command at `C:\Users\Work\Desktop\School Work\load_database.sql` and when I type `\i "C:\Users\Work\Desktop\School Work\load_database.sql"` it says `C:: permission denied`. How can I fix this?

I found a work around [here](http://forums.devshed.com/postgresql-help-21/run-sql-script-from-command-prompt-407999.html) where you copy the .sql file to the same folder as psql.exe is in.

By the way, does [\i](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) stand for import?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You've just run into a peculiarity of `psql` on Windows.

In my comment I just wanted to exclude the possibility that you *really* didn't have the necessary permission.  Then it turned out that even on Windows, you have to use 'normal' slashes instead of backslashes, that is:

```
\i 'C:/Users/Work/Desktop/School Work/load_database.sql'
```

should work fine regardless which folder you start `psql` from.  Notice that I used single quotes - with double quotes you'd got

```
"C:/Users/Work/Desktop/School Work/load_database.sql": Invalid argument
```

Comment: Got it thanks. How did you know to use single and not double quotes? Is that a general rule for postgres or what's the difference?

Comment: @Celeritas I think it is the result of a conflict of how Windows uses double quotes in paths and how `psql` (and PostgreSQL) use it in identifiers.

Comment: this didn´t work for me in windows10, forward slashes and all, [user68006's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165867/105565) did, though

Comment: @Scaramouche thanks for the feedback!  Apparently, not all permissions denied are created equal.

Comment: Backslashes can be used if they're escaped (by being doubled) and inside a string delimited by single quotes: `\i 'c:\\some\\path\\myscript.sql'` does work as well as `\i 'c:/some/path/myscript.sql'`

Answer (score 9):

Put the file in some directory with full permission to everyone, like 'c:\tmp'

OR

Set read privileges to the file you want to import.

I put 'Everyone' reading permission.

After importing the file, you could revoke that permission.

[image: windows file properties]

Comment: There's no permissions issue here -- it's that the string has to be written in a way that `pqsl` likes.  We know the permissions aren't a problem because the error says "C:" is the problem, not the whole file name.